# Binding data from firebase database to Angular2 view

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase

I am using firebase 2 database.i want to display the title object of listings collection in the firebase database.

i binded like this

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let listing of listings">
    {{listing.title}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

while consoling all fields are listing.

`{{listing.$key}}and {{listing.$value}}` are working fine.
But selecting a particular object is not working.

Comment: please help me anyone.

Comment: Please add more detail to the question. What does your object look like? What does your ts code looks like? Can you include a screenshot of the `console.log` from your `listings` field?

Comment: not enough info. what do you mean by selecting a particular object is not working. what did u try?